# How do I configure proxy settings for TeamCity?

Tags: svn, proxy, teamcity

We have a TeamCity server sitting behind a cooperate proxy. We use several of the Castle open source libraries. I want to set up CI builds for the Castle stack internally, so that I can create dependent builds for our core shared libs. Everything was going well, until I tried to find proxy settings for TeamCity. Google-ing around has turned up nothing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Web proxy? Why does TeamCity need to talk to the web? Doesn't it just needs to talk to your source control and maybe an email server? Or are you asking about configuring access to the Castle Project git repositories - wouldn't that be a proxy configuration of git on your build server?

Comment: Ah, missed the svn tag when I commented - sorry,

Comment: How about when Teamcity is using NuGet to auto update its packages?

Comment: I ended up modifying my proxy settings within Internet Options via the control panel or IE options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure a proxy for svn access from your TeamCity server then this is probably easiest done by configuring a svn proxy as usual for the user account that makes the svn fetches. I know CruiseControl.NET better than TeamCity but for CC.NET it's the account that's the main service runs as.

You'll find this at one of

- C:\Users\AccountName\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers on Vista/7/2008 (domain account)
- C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers on Vista/7/2008 (service account)
- C:\Documents and Settings\AccountName\Application Data\Subversion\servers on XP/2003

You'll probably want to set up the proxy in the [global] section at the bottom of the file - uncomment and fill in at least the http-proxy-host and http-proxy-port lines.

Comment: That might do it. Didn't think to just configure svn on the machine. Will have to figure out if TeamCity uses whatever is on the machine or if it has its own built in SVN client.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point :-/ Most SVN clients use the same core libraries and so keep their configuration in the same place but TeamCity is Java so might use SVNKit which might use somewhere else. Hope it works!